# How to open a localhost server accessible from all devices in C# Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms, networking, localhost

I'm building a C# (Windows Forms) application that should open a local server on the network. I've searched and googled thoroughly but it seems that nobody was exposed to the same problem that I have.

The code I'm posting below does indeed open up a localhost in the given port *(when ran through VS or as a normal build)*, but the problem is, it's only accessible through my laptop. If I go to the IP address and port through my phone or any another laptop, it doesn't even find the server. After several tries and brainstorming. It seems to me that it doesn't really open up the server on the network per se. It just creates some sort of a virtual localhost accessible to and through the machine which ran the code only.

**This is my code:**

```
private HttpListener Listener = null;

//CHECK IF HTTP IS SUPPORTED
try
{
    Listener = new HttpListener();
    Listener.Prefixes.Add("http://localhost:3000/");
    Listener.Start();
    Listener.BeginGetContext(GetContextCallback, null);
}
catch {} //SUPPRESS THE EXCEPTION/ERROR

private void GetContextCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        // Get the context
        var context = Listener.EndGetContext(ar);

        // listen for the next request
        Listener.BeginGetContext(GetContextCallback, null);

        var responseString = string.Format("Hello, this is a template text");

        byte[] buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(responseString);

        // and send it
        var response = context.Response;
        response.ContentType = "text/html";
        response.ContentLength64 = buffer.Length;
        response.StatusCode = 200;
        response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        response.OutputStream.Close();
    }
```

I'm not unfamiliar with either the concept or C# itself. I've built several applications that do the same with **Node.js** and have built a handful of apps in C#. But this is my first try writing such an application in C#. What am I missing?

Comment: Yes, your phone has its own LocalHost.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I'm not trying to access the local server from my phone using localhost but rather the network's IP address. For example: "192.168.1.3:3000"

Comment: @HenkHolterman I'm not trying to access the local server from my phone using localhost but rather the network's IP address. For example: "192.168.1.3:3000"

Comment: I know. But I wouldn't use a phone, too many variables. Test with the other laptop.

Comment: Already have, same issue.

Comment: The server application is closing.  You have no blocking method to prevent code from exiting after the connection is opened.  You should be able to see port 3000 status when from cmd.exe you use the following : Netstat -a.  A simple way of blocking just for testing is to add Console.ReadLine() to prevent the code from exiting.

Comment: Install a tool such as Wireshark to check if the request actually arrives from your phone, https://www.wireshark.org. If it never lands there, it is a network/router issue.

Comment: @jdweng Where exactly would I put `Console.ReadLine()`? I put it in several places including inside the try block as well as the method. But i'm worried these might be the wrong places.

Comment: Any place After you start the listener.  The correct method would to use a semaphore like WaitOne (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.waithandle.waitone?view=netframework-4.8)  The wait one you can unblock from your code while a ReadLine() requires the operator to press the return key to continue.